# How to propagate SQL Messages Tab output through Dapper

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, dapper

Does anyone know how I can get the Messages Tab output to propagate through Dapper to my C# code so I can display it somewhere?

Currently, I am aware of how to get the rows affected count and exceptions, but not much else.

```
public static void ExecuteSqlCommand(string connectionString, string sql)
{
    using (var db = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        var count = db.Execute(sql, null, null, 240); 
        Console.WriteLine(count); //can get count of rows affected but not rest of output from Messages Tab in SSMS.
    }
}
```

I have tried running SQL Server Profiler to see if the messages are being shown there but didn't see anything either. I know from running my SQL script in SQL Server Management Studio that a message does get created, it just doesn't seem to be going anywhere.

I have investigated db.InfoMessage but have not got that working and am becoming a bit pushed for time.

For example, when I run a create table script that needs correcting, I get a message "Warning! The maximum key length is 900 bytes. The index 'UQ_UniqueMachineInfo' has maximum length of 2428 bytes. For some combination of large values, the insert/update operation will fail." which I need to show through code.

Comment: I'm now wondering whether I should adjust my question and title to show that dapper really has nothing to do with the displaying of the SQL message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not wiring up an event handler to the InfoMessage event on the connection.

```
public static void ExecuteSqlCommand(string connectionString, string sql)
{
    using (var db = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        db.InfoMessage += new SqlInfoMessageEventHandler(db_InfoMessage);
        var count = db.Execute(sql, null, null, 240); 
        Console.WriteLine(count); //can get count of rows affected but not rest of output from Messages Tab in SSMS.
    }
}

void db_InfoMessage(object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e)
{
    // handle here and look at e.Message
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this has worked fine. I actually had similar code while trying to get it to show but I must have messed something up.